# How to specify decimal precision and scale number in MySQL using phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

SQL enables MySQL users to allocate a filed in Decimal format with specific Precision and Scale numbers as:

```
CREATE TABLE test_table
(
    test_column DECIMAL(6,4) NOT NULL
);
```

How can I do this in phpMyAdmin as the field type has only length/value option available there?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Decimals can be added to a MySQL database by using the `DECIMAL(M,D)` data type. This requires 2 arguments.

- M is the maximum number of digits, ranging from 1 to 65.
- D is the number of decimal places available, ranging from 0 to 30.

Note that with `D` digits reserved for decimal places, there can be at most `M-D` digits available for the integer part. So if we use `DECIMAL(6,4)`, the number `45.8239` would be valid, but `456.12` would not.

To use this in phpMyAdmin, you can do the following:

In the `Length/Value` field type `6,4` without the parentheses.

[image]

results in a table structure like this:

[image]