# Can't get the right side decimal value different from 0 in mysql(phpmyadmin)

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

In phpmydamin I'm trying to create a field with datatype decimal(4,2) but when i do it, mysql always change to 4,0 when i save it. I tried other right side numbers, like 4,4 or others, but it always saves to 4,0.

What i am missing here?

Thank you

[image: before saving...]
Before saving...

[image: after saving...]
After saving..

Comment: how do you know that it changes it to 4,0 and what do you mean by "save" and what do you mean by "it" ?

Comment: well, im doing it in phpmyadmin. Basically when i add a new field to the table with decimal(4,4) and then i save it(because it's what says in the interface) i can see in the created field 4,0

Comment: Please have a look on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23877564/7564182).

Comment: yes, that's what i did. I even tried to use the same values as explained in the answer, but when i see the result after saved it saves as 6,0

Comment: maybe a known bug: https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/12480? - provide more information about your phpmyadmin installation (version, apache, os).

Comment: It's a phpmyadmin bug:

https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/12500

Answer (score 0):

It's a phpmyadmin bug
[github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/12500](http://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/12500)

Just update phpmyadmin.